# Select the record that includes NULL value in SQL and Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, select

I have Python code that is connected to the SQL Server for this I am using `PYODBC` with **wildcard in order to accept user input**, I am trying to perform a **Select query**

I want to return the  the count of records based on the user input where he can input on the displayed fields or leave it empty  and then apply the select query based on the requested search.

The problem is that when I try the query on the SQL Server Management Studio it returns the correct result with records that includes **Null**

But when I tried in the python script it returns just the records that doesn't include **Null values**

NOTE: the `ANSI_NULLS`  for this database is **ON**;

In the below query I am trying to return the count of the records where the `gender ='F'`  and `status_type = 'Expired'`

In SSMS:

```
select count(*)
from card
where gender = 'F'
and status_type = 3
group by status_type
```

returns result  = 7 ==> correct answer.

In Python Script:

```
sql = ('''select count(*)
                  , c3.status 
          from card C 
          LEFT JOIN status_type c3 ON c3.ID = c.status_type
          where
         (c.nickname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL)
          and
          c.gender = ?
          and 
          c3.status = ?
          Group by c3.status
          ''')

param1 = nickname_search                    
param2 = radio_gender
param3 = radio_status
 
rows = cursor.execute(sql,[
                         param1,param1,
                         param2,
                         param3
                         ]).fetchall()
```

**the return result  =  2  ==> the expected result = 7**

where 2 is the records that has `nickname` **not Null**

My question how to return the values that includes also **NULL values**  in the **nickname column**?

Comment: Your two queries are quite different, you filter by and group by status in your Python script.

Comment: in my python script i want to allow the user to enter a nickname but its not mandatory  for this i put   `OR ? IS NULL` in the **nickname**

in my query i forgot to group by `status_type`

Comment: Double check your parameters and query. You define `param1` as `nickname_search`, which you pass in the clause `c.gender = ?` and `LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`. `Param2` is `radio_gender` so you check if that is `NULL`, and then finally check if `c3.status` has the same value as `radio_status`.

Comment: Effectively you have the following : `where c.gender = {nickname_search} AND (c.nickname LIKE CONCAT('%', {nickname_search}, '%') OR {radio_gender} IS NULL) AND c3.status = {radio_status}`

Comment: @Larnu sorry for the misleading in the typing i will edit my question

Comment: You're not misleading, the problem is your parameters are being passed incorrectly.

Comment: yes i correct the query but now  if the user select the same parameters as the **SQL query**  and leave the nickname field empty ...it return count of records  that has `nickname` **not Null** so it return 2 where it must return 7

Comment: so to clarify what i want is to display several fields that allow the user to input  some values  but with allowing him to leave it empty. As many the user insert input as the query will be narrowed and return the required result based on the user input

Comment: So *all* the parameters should be `NULL`able?

Comment: the most of it yes... its like advanced search where the user can insert as many parameters in order to get the required request

Comment: anyone had an answer ??

Comment: So when the user doesn't type anything into `nickname_search` does that variable hold an empty string `""` or does it hold the Python `None` value?

Comment: it handle empty string witch in the SQL database is NULL